# Google App Engine: 404 Resource not found

Tags: python, database, google-app-engine

I am trying to build a basic blog model using Google App Engine in Python. However, something's wrong with my code I suppose, and I am getting a 404 error when I try to display all the posted blog entries on a single page. Here's the python code:

```
import os
import re
import webapp2
import jinja2
from string import letters
from google.appengine.ext import db

template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')
jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir),     autoescape=True)

class Handler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def write(self, *a, **kw):
        self.response.out.write(*a, **kw)
    def render_str(self, template, **params):
        t = jinja_env.get_template(template)
        return t.render(params)
    def render(self, template, **kw):
        self.write(self.render_str(template, **kw))

def post_key(name = "dad"):
    return db.Key.from_path('blog', name)

class Blogger(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    content = db.TextProperty()
    created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)

    def render(self):
        self._render_text = self.content.replace('\n', '<br>')
        return render_str("post.html", p = self)

class MainPage(Handler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write("Visit our blog")

class BlogHandler(Handler):
    def get(self):
        posts = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Blogger order by created desc")
        self.render("frontblog.html", posts = posts)    

class SubmitHandler(Handler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("temp.html")    
    def post(self):
        name = self.request.get("name")
        content = self.request.get("content")
        if name and content:
            a = Blogger(name = name, content = content, parent = post_key())
            a.put()
            self.redirect('/blog/%s' % str(a.key().id()))
        else:
            error = "Fill in both the columns!"
            self.render("temp.html", name = name, content = content, error =     error)        

class DisplayPost(Handler):
    def get(self, post_id):
        po = Blogger.get_by_id(int(post_id))
        if po:
            self.render("perma.html", po = po)
        else:
            self.response.write("404 Error")        

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),
                          ('/blog', BlogHandler), 
                          ('/blog/submit', SubmitHandler),
                          ('/blog/([0-9]+)', DisplayPost)], debug=True)
```

After posting my content, it gets redirected to a permalink. However, this is the error I am getting on submitting my post:

```
404 Not Found
The resource could not be found
```

Here's the frontblog.html source code, in case that would help:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <title>CS 253 Blog</title>
</head>

<body>
  <a href="/blog">
    CS 253 Blog
  </a>

  <div id="content">
  {% block content %}
      {%for post in posts%}
        {{post.render() | safe}}
        <br></br>
      {%endfor%}
  {% endblock %}
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

So basically, I am not being redirected to the permalink page. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: 1. look at your app.yaml file, is the application registered inside? 2. do you really get posts data? log the posts data to check. if you remove the posts and display "hello world" instead, will that show? I'm not familiar with db, I use ndb for my applications

Answer (score 1):

When you create your post, you're giving it a parent (not sure why). But when you get it, you do so by the ID only, and don't take into account the parent ID. In the datastore, a key is actually a path consisting of all the parent kinds and IDs/names and then those of the current entity, and to get an object you need to pass the full path.

Possible solutions here:

- Drop the parent key, since it isn't doing anything here as you're always setting it to the same value;
- Use it when you get the object: `Blogger.get_by_id(post_id, parent=parent_key())` - obviously this only works if the parent is always the same;
- Use the full stringified key in the path, rather than just the ID, and do `Blogger.get(key)` - you'll also need to change the route regex to accept alphanumeric chars, eg `'/blog/(\w+)'`, and change the redirect to `'/blog/%s' % a.key()`.

Comment: Tried the first 2 solutions. However, I still get the same error. Also,  i just noticed that the error page is redirected to '/sub'. Is this the default error path? Because nowhere have I made a Handler for that path.

Comment: No, there's no `sub` path by default. Exactly where are you getting that?

Comment: just when I submit the name and content on the '/blog/submit' page. Instead of getting redirected to a permalink page, I get redirected to '/sub' and get the 404 error message!

Comment: Hmm, well the fact that "sub" is a substring of "submit" is suggestive, but I can't see what's doing that.

Comment: I know. That's really weird. Also, when I checked the SDK, i can see that posts aren't being stored in the database either.